# Default Mysql SSL connection faling after overriding default kaystore to custom keystore

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have Mysql 8.0.19 as docker instance.
In our application previously we use JDK's default keystore for SSL.
With JDK's keystore connection to Mysql server is just fine with SSL and without SSL.
Here we didnt configured the SSL for Mysql manually. We are using default SSL mechanism of Mysql.

Now for some reason we decided to use our own keystore and to use that we overrided the keystore for JVM with below variables

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=$keystorePath$
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=$sslKeyStorePwd$
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=$keystorePath$"
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=$sslKeyStorePwd$
```

Now after this, connection to mysql for SSL is faling with below errors

```
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|01|main|2021-08-10 16:20:30.019 IST|TransportContext.java:313|Fatal (UNKNOWN_CA): Received fatal alert: unknown_ca (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:128)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:279)
    
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
```

In /var/lib/mysql/ we have
ca.pem,ca-key.pem,client-cert.pem,client-key.pem,        public_key.pem,private_key.pem,server-cert.pem, server-key.pem.

To resolve this error I tried to import the ca.pem,client-cert.pem, server-cert.pem into our keystore but it didnt worked.

Answer (score 0):

`unknown_ca` means that the certificate was not signed by a trusted Certificate Authority. My guess is that you do not have the whole chain in your keystore

Comment: So here exactly which certificates need to import. So even I import ca.pem,client-cert.pem, server-cert.pem which are coming from mysql itself..its giving same error.

Comment: You need to check your certificate (the one use when connecting). It usually is signed by a CA (and often by an intermediate CA). You will need to add the intermediate in the keystore and the parent CA in the truststore. Since it works with default keystore, I guess you have them in there.

Comment: I already tried by importing the  ca.pem,client-cert.pem, server-cert.pem which are coming from mysql installation itself for default SSL but it didn't helped.

Comment: The certificate you are talking about are signed by a CA (or multiple in a chain) and you need to import the whole chain.

Comment: We have only those certificate in the installation of mysql. It seems we don't have whole chain there. When I looked at jdk-11.0.3\lib\security\cacerts file with which it was working fine previously, there are many entries and which is used by Mysql is not clear. So not able to understand which certificates need to be imported.

Comment: You can find that out with f.ex. openssl CLI: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368123/how-to-extract-the-root-ca-and-subordinate-ca-from-a-certificate-chain-in-linux

Comment: Actually here we are not sure about exact which certificate used  by mysql for connection while using default keystore of jdk as said previously. How should we find that?  If we know that then may be we can do the things mentioned in above URL